# Помощь в python в pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

Я загрузил несколько изображений под один str для анимации, ... Хочу массово изменить разрешение. Подскажите как??? Снизу вариант не помогает.

```
WalkRight = [pygame.image.load('Walk_000.png'), pygame.image.load('Walk_001.png'), pygame.image.load('Walk_002.png'), pygame.image.load('Walk003.png'), pygame.image.load('Walk_004.png')]
WalkRight = pygame.transform.scale(WalkRight, (40, 60))
```

Выдаёт ошибку.

[image: <code>введите сюда описание изображения</code>]

Comment: Раз выдает ошибку, значит надо ее прочитать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не добавляйте вывод терминала и ошибки скриншотами. Неудобно читать, невозможно копировать. Другие люди с такой же ошибкой не смогут выйти на этот вопрос

Comment: Попробуйте так: `WalkRight = [pygame.transform.scale(img, (40, 60)) for img in WalkRight]`

Answer (score 0):

```py
# Для удобства работы с кодом лучше делать так
# Если у вас в коде нет функций с такими же именами
from pygame.image import load
from pygame.transform import scale

WalkRight = [load('Walk_000.png'),load('Walk_001.png'), \
    load('Walk_002.png'), load('Walk003.png'), load('Walk_004.png')]

# Новый список измененных изображений
WalkRight = [scale(img, (40, 60)) for img in WalkRight]
```